# Slice of interface...how can I make this safe for concurrent use?

Tags: go, concurrency

I have the following code https://play.golang.org/p/4mlXMhqpLJ:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Name string
}

func (a *A) method(name string) {
    a.Name = name
}

func (a *A) name() string {
    return a.Name
}

type intt interface {
    method(string)
    name() string
}

var interfacer = []intt{
    &A{},
}

func ExportedMethod(name string) bool {
    for _, aa := range interfacer {
        fmt.Println("Pre:", aa.name())
        aa.method(name)
        fmt.Println("Post:", aa.name())
        if aa.name() == "Fred" {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    ExportedMethod("Bob")
    ExportedMethod("Frank")
}
```

Since my second for loop prints Bob it is apparent that this is not safe for concurrent use. This is a simple example. In reality, I have many more structs that are going to satisfy interfacer...&B{}, &C{}, &D{}, &E{}, etc...I need a way to be able to loop through all of the structs, which is why I have a slice of interfacer. How can I make this safe for concurrent use?

Comment: You can use `sync.Mutex` or `sync.RWMutex` to make it safe for concurrent use.

Comment: It doesn't seem very idiomatic to me to keep the state of the last access around. I'd like to "start clean" each time I access it.

Comment: "*Since my second for loop prints Bob it is apparent that this is not safe for concurrent use.*" I don't think I understand what you're trying to demonstrate. `ExportedMethod` alters the elements of the global `interfacer`. That appears to be its purpose. You called it twice, so it should be no surprise that a second call also modified `interfacer` and the changes from the first call are still there. The simple solution would seem to be to not modify the same array twice, and also don't use a global. Is there something else?

Comment: You kinda writing this code like Private and Public methods from Java.. thats not very Go either.. You've already exported your field and sync.Mutex is very idiomatic

Comment: @Schwern that's my question....is there a better way than a slice of interfacer so that it doesn't modify?

Comment: @reticentroot: I'm not questioning where sync.Mutex is idiomatic....what isn't idiomatic is seeing state from a prior access.

Comment: @kristen If I understand, you don't want the elements of `interfacer` modified. But you're calling a method that modifies the elements of `interfacer`. So... don't call that method? Change the method so it doesn't modify the elements of `interfacer`? Copy them before modifying? Sorry, I'm pretty sure I still don't understand.

Comment: I agree your post is still unclear.. however to test for concurrent safely use the `race` flag https://golang.org/doc/articles/race_detector.html if the print order is not what you expect then thats normal async behavior... that being said.. nothing about the code above is concurrent. There are no gorountines or channels being used. Lastly, if the code were running in goroutines, the log package is safe for concurrent printing.. fmt is not.

Comment: Here's an example of your code that is concurrent. https://play.golang.org/p/yXDGaAECtX, in this example `mx` is not exported and therefore not exposed and cannot be accessed outside of it's package.  So state is hidden.